# PowerPivot Calculated Column Circular Dependency

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I'm really spinning my wheels on this one. I'm trying to add 2 calculated columns in a Power Pivot table (in Excel 2013) to a loaded single column.

Setup (just first row shown):

```
Prd | Beg                                                      | End
1   | =CALCULATE(SUM([End]),Table[Prd]=EARLIER([Prd])-1)       | =[Beg]+[Prd]
```

I want it to calculate like this:

```
Prd | Beg | End
1   | 1   | 2
2   | 2   | 4
3   | 4   | 7
```

But no matter what I do, I get a circular reference error because the [End] calculation is pointing to the [Beg] calculation and vice versa. I'm trying to get it to perform a rolling calculation where the [Beg] amount always equals the [End] amount from the prior [Prd].

I tried various calculations using SUMX and ALLEXCEPT, but I'm not getting this one right. I even tried designating the Row Identifier in the Table Behavior tab based on [this](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-circular-dependencies/) but it's not working with that either.

Appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Could you indicate the structure of the table.

Comment: That is the structure. It starts with a 1 column table. Column Beg and End are calculated columns that reference the initial column ("Prd"). The idea is to create a "rolling" value period over period.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to base your formula for **[Beg]** column on previous values of **[Prd]** column. Therefore

```
Beg=SUMX(
         FILTER(  
                ALL(Table[Prd]),   
                Table[Prd] < EARLIER(Table[Prd])
               ),
         Table[Prd]
        ) + 1
```

**Explanation**:
It sums up all the previous values for [Prd] column and adds 1 (if you take a look at the generated values, you'll see the pattern).

But the formula for **[End]** should also be fixed so you won't run into the same exception. So you'll have the following (this will sum values from current row for **[Beg]** and **[Prd]**):

```
End=SUMX(
         FILTER(
                ALL(Table[Beg], Table[Prd]), 
                Table[Prd]=EARLIER(Table[Prd])),Table[Beg]
        ) + Table[Prd]
```

**Explanation**:
In your case, avoiding to use **CALCULATE** and using instead just **SUMX** and **EARLIER** for **[End]** will help you to get rid of circular dependency.